# CASE WHEN textfield does not equal a value

Tags: netsuite

In a Netsuite saved search I am trying to create a formula that - in part - gives a field value if a textfield does not equal a word - in this case the word is "consol". I tried the below but got an error and am lost on how I can accomplish this.

```
CASE WHEN {custbody_eym_exhibitor_name} = 'Consol' THEN {custrecord511.custrecord501} WHEN {custrecord169.custrecord173} IS NOT NULL AND {custbody_eym_exhibitor_name} IS NOT 'Consol' THEN {custrecord169.custrecord173} ELSE {custbody90} END
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know [Suite Answer Id 10101](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10101/kw/10101#bridgehead_N2839038) suggest you'd be able to do `CASE WHEN -- THEN -- WHEN -- THEN -- ELSE -- END`.  However, this has never worked for me in a saved search.  I've always have to do `CASE WHEN -- THEN -- ELSE (CASE WHEN -- THEN -- ELSE -- END) END`.

If you are trying to do the following:

If custbody_eym_exhibitor_name is Consol then return custrecord511.custrecord501, and stop evaluating.

If custbody_eym_exhibitor_name is not Consol then check if custrecord169.custrecord173 is NULL, and continue evaluating.

If custrecord169.custrecord173 is NULL then return custbody90, and stop evaluating. If custrecord169.custrecord173 is not NULL then return custrecord169.custrecord173, and stop evaluating.

This should work:

```
CASE WHEN {custbody_eym_exhibitor_name}='Consol' THEN {custrecord511.custrecord501} ELSE NVL({custrecord169.custrecord173},{custbody90}) END
```

If you wanted to check if custbody_eym_exhibitor_name contains Consol change `{custbody_eym_exhibitor_name}='Consol'` to `{custbody_eym_exhibitor_name} LIKE '%Consol%'` .

Also both tests for 'Consol' will be case sensitive.  To work around this you can change `{custbody_eym_exhibitor_name}='Consol'` to `LOWER({custbody_eym_exhibitor_name})='consol'`